# How to track whenever a component view is updated?

Tags: swiftui

I want to track when a given view is reloaded. How do I do that?
I was thinking of printing something, but I cannot put print() in the body of a SwiftUI view

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
struct Demo: View {
  var body: some View {
     print("<< updated")
     return Group {
         // ... your views here
     }
  }
}
```

if you have at top some container view you can return it directly, for example

```
  var body: some View {
     print("<< updated")
     return VStack {
         Text("Some 1")
         Text("Some 2")
         Text("Some 3")
     }
  }
```

the common rule - it must be returned single view